# Terraform ECS EC2 ASG how to zero task instance stop

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

autoscaling code

```
module "autoscaling" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/autoscaling/aws"
  version = "~> 6.5"

  name = "${local.name}-asg"

  security_groups = [module.autoscaling_sg.security_group_id]
  ignore_desired_capacity_changes = true

  image_id = jsondecode(data.aws_ssm_parameter.ecs_optimized_ami.value)["image_id"]
  instance_type = "t4g.small"
  key_name = "dpgg-match"

  user_data = base64encode(local.user_data)
  
  network_interfaces = [
    {
      associate_public_ip_address = true
      delete_on_termination       = true
    }
  ]

  block_device_mappings = [
    {
      device_name = "/dev/xvda"
      ebs = {
        volume_size = 40
        volume_type = "gp2"
      }
    }
  ]

  create_iam_instance_profile = true
  iam_role_name               = local.name
  iam_role_description        = "ECS role for ${local.name}"
  iam_role_policies = {
    AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
    AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore        = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore"
  }

  vpc_zone_identifier = module.vpc.public_subnets
  health_check_type   = "EC2"
  min_size            = 0
  max_size            = 3
  desired_capacity    = 1

  termination_policies = ["OldestInstance"]

  autoscaling_group_tags = {
    ECS = "True"
    Terraform = "True"
  }

  tags = local.tags
}
```

How can I automatically stop instances with zero task running in the ECS EC2 Autoscaling Group?

When I searched on Google, I was told to change termination_policies to OldestInstance option, but it was not effective.

Answer (score 1):

The OldestInstance option tells ASG *in which order* to terminate instances, but not *when*. What you are looking for is [ECS Capacity Providers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers.html):

> When you use an Auto Scaling group capacity provider with managed scaling turned on, Amazon ECS creates two custom CloudWatch metrics and a target tracking scaling policy that attaches to your Auto Scaling group. Amazon ECS then manages the scale-in and scale-out actions of the Auto Scaling group **based on the load your tasks put on your cluster**.

More details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html